# PHP precedence for && and parentheses

Tags: php

According to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

> Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary.

However, it seems && remains higher:

```
$var = null;
var_dump($var && ($var->a() || $var->b()) && $var->c());
```

I expect `($var->a() || $var->b())` to be evaluated first, due to the brackets, and throw an error for the missing method. However, the result is `bool(false)` with no error. How so?

Comment: `if(func1 || func2) {....}` If the machine already knows that func1 is true, why even execute func2?  What would be the benefit?

Comment: The brackets only change that && would be evaluated before ||. (Without them, you would have `(A && B) || (C && D)` here – brackets added for explicit clarity.) But they don’t change anything about the fact that `A && B && C` gets evaluated from left to right, and since it’s `&&`, that process can be broken off after the _first_ false-y value was encountered.

Comment: **Why** do you expect that? I would assume that `null && anything` is false

Comment: It's not about precendence, it's about short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Basics

[Not the full statements gets checked](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01c3fe0682fd333ee7c85941f73b524e68b55a88)

```
function A (){ echo "ran A\n"; return false;}
function B (){ echo "ran B\n"; return true;}

if( A && B ){
    echo 'Both true';
} else{
    echo 'One or both false';
}
```

Both must be true, but A isn't true, why bother checking the rest? No matter what `B` returns, the statement will never be true and it will be the else{} (and get '*ran A*' and NOT get '*ran B*').

---

##### Parenthesis

Also, precendence gets prioritized with brackets, but it still goes from left to right:

```
if( A && (B or C) && D)
```

- `A` will run. If it's false, no point in continueing. B/C/D dont run
- If `A=true` `B` will run.

  - If `B=true` `C` wont run, as only one true is needed. Then `D` is run
  - If `B=false` `C` will run

    - if `C=true` `D` is run
    - if `C=false` (and `B` also is) the inners of the parenthesis are 2xfalse -> false. `D` wont run as it wont matter

---

When you understand this concept, you can use this trick to your benefit. An example with the `??` operator:

```
$thing = $user->getThing() ?? $user->makeNewThing();
```

You try to get $thing from the user object. If it exists you get it and `makeNewThing()` never gets called (as it would be useless, to optimized away). If ity doesnt, only then it gets ran.

Comment: I must be reading the documentation too literal, ignoring optimisations perhaps. I thought `if( A() && (B() && B()) )` would run B first.

Comment: @Alex operator precedence is about which of two _different_ operators has the higher priority, “binds” the parts together stronger. When only one operator type is involved, then precedence doesn’t apply to begin with.

Comment: I've added a more complex example, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Martijn and @CBroe I get it now. I was going for the same approach as doing math in my head: `2 * (1 + 3)` thinking, "first, do 1 plus 3", whereas that's not what happens here.

Answer (score 3):

From [the official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

See [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).